# How can I access order items in the hook woocommerce_new_order?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, tribe-event-tickets

`woocommerce_new_order` fires before order items are assigned to the order, thus making `$order->get_items();` return an empty array.

Is there any way to get the items using that hook?

The order is created using `wc_new_order` so using `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` won't work.

Is there another hook that could be used?

I'm using The Events Calendar and with it they have a functionality to move an event attendee from one event to another.

I use the hook `tribe_tickets_ticket_moved` (https://docs.theeventscalendar.com/reference/hooks/tribe_tickets_ticket_moved/) but for some reason(??) they do not pass the new order_id with the hook. So I resolved myself to check for new orders using `woocommerce_new_order` with a couple check to make sure the new order comes from the ticket moving and that its the right one.

They even set `parent_id` on the new order, but nothing on the old one to link them together.

I'm not sure how I could access the new order from the `ticket_moved` hook, or getting the items in the `woocommerce_new_order` hook.

Comment: You can get the order item from the order in the hook '`do_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', $order->get_id(), $order );`

Comment: @mujuonly $order->get_items() returns empty. the items have not yet been posted to the order

Answer (score 1):

Since WooCommerce 4.3.0 the correct hook to be used to get `$order->get_items();` is `woocommerce_checkout_order_created`.

```
function after_order_placed( $order ) {

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

      $custom_meta = $item->get_meta('Custom Key');
  
    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'after_order_placed' );
```

This [hook is located](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.5.2/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L403) inside [create_order()](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.5.2/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L304-L418) method for `WC_Checkout` Class.

**Note:** The code will not work for manual created orders via admin.